# CSS animation not timed correctly

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm displaying a word that goes to each corner of the screen within 5 seconds. The problem I have is that the animation doesn't seem to stay as long as it should in each corner.

**[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/6qjrn0zv/)**

```css
#lorem {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 50px;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3%; left: 3%;
    animation: switch 5s linear infinite 0s;
}

@keyframes switch {
    25% { left:auto; right:3%; }
    50% { top:auto; bottom:3%; }
    75% { right:auto; left:3%; }
    100% { bottom:auto; top:3%; }
}
```

```html
<span id="lorem">Lorem</span>
```

Comment: How long should it stay...your request is unclear.

Comment: ^seems to be 5 seconds? animation: switch 5s linear infinite 0s;

Comment: Yes the total animation lasts 5 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide all values instead of only the once you think you change. You aren't *overwriting* previous values, you are transitioning from one to the other.

http://jsfiddle.net/6qjrn0zv/2/

```
#lorem {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3%;
    left: 3%;
    animation: switch 4s linear infinite forwards;
}
@keyframes switch {
    0% {
        top: 3%;
        right: auto;
        bottom: auto;
        left: 3%;
    }
    25% {
        top: 3%;
        right: 3%;
        bottom: auto;
        left: auto;
    }
    50% {
        top: auto;
        right: 3%;
        bottom: 3%;
        left: auto;
    }
    75% {
        top: auto;
        right: auto;
        bottom: 3%;
        left: 3%;
    }
}
```